# Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth2

Есть сервис с авторизацией через OAuth2 (например, vk.com). Есть `clientId` и `clientSecret`. Нужно написать демона, который будет делать какие-то запросы к API сервиса.

Возможно ли это сделать в фоновом режиме и автоматически получать access_token по истечению срока? Например, многие сервисы после авторизации больше не запрашивают данные пользователя.

UPD. Мне нужно сохранять access_token (например, в БД), а потом из обычного потока работать с `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

```
public void run() {
    // access_token = получаем из БД сохраненный access_token.
    // создаем restTemplate из access_token
    while (true) {
        Map map = restTemplate.getForObject(..., Map.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вполне возможно. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Темкатоже, а каким образом работать с `OAuth2RestTemplate` из какого-нибудь обычного потока (`new Thread().start()`)? Ведь доступа не будет к  `OAuth2Request`, который обрабатывается спрингом.

Comment: Есть такая класс [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html#processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(java.lang.Object)), который позволяет заинъектировать в произвольный объект spring-бины. Однако это говорит о том, что у вас явные проблемы с архитектурой, если используется `new Thread().start()`

Comment: @Темкатоже, у меня есть множество токенов полученных от разных пользователей. Мне нужно работать с ними параллельно, то есть меня интересует выполнение запросов от их лица, а не авторизация через сторонние сервисы в моем приложении. Для многопоточности на самом деле можно и Executor/RxJava использовать, но суть в том, что контекст Spring Security & Spring MVC теряется внутри.

Comment: А вы пробовали решить вопрос с помощью @Scheduled? Будет запускаться отдельный поток через экзекутор и по удобному для вас расписанию.

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok, в методе помеченном как Scheduled мне хотелось бы уметь распараллелить работу на несколько потоков, при этом контекст также не отнаследуется. Основная нагрузка идет на IO, поэтому делать это в простом цикле будет не эффективно.

Comment: Мне так и не понятна в чем твоя проблема. Наследуйся от [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html?is-external=true), передай туда параметрами нужные бины (или заинъекти через SpringBeanAutowiringSupport) и рабочие данные, а после запускай их при помощи [TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) или [AsyncTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor.html). Про какой контекст ты говоришь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих попыток рецепт получился следующим.

1. Получаем `access_token` из базы данных в новом потоке;
2. Оборачиваем его в `DefaultOAuth2AccessToken`;
3. Создаем `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` и добавляем в него `DefaultOAuth2AccessToken`;
4. Создаем `OAuth2RestTemplate` с настройками и установленным контекстом.
5. Выполняем запросы и ловим `UserRedirectRequiredException`. Исключение означает, что ключ больше не валидный и нужно запросить новый у пользователя через контроллер.